# Scroll to center of horizontal div

Tags: javascript, web

I have following `<div>` on my page. Amount of black squares depends on user input. How can I scroll to horizontal center of this block using JS?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center that, you need to use the `scrollLeft` property.

```js
document.body.scrollLeft = (document.body.scrollWidth - document.body.clientWidth) / 2
```

Of course, for your problem, you need to get the reference of that div. Above code is a reference on how you scroll towards the center of a horizontal bar.